# indent HTML and CSScode using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, indentation

I have a small web application that outputs html and css code at the end, but it's necessary to reindent the output, especially the css. I found this library: https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify
But it doesn't seem to work. For instance, one of the files says:

```
Usage:
style_html(html_source);
style_html(html_source, options);
```

but all I get is an error: style_html is not defined. I've included one set of script tags as it says in the usage section.

example:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.6.8/beautify.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.6.8/beautify-css.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.6.8/beautify-html.min.js"></script>

    <script> style_html("asdf");</script>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

See [the source code](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-beautify/1.6.8/beautify-html.js):

> ```
> // If we're running a web page and don't have either of the above, add our one global
> window.html_beautify = function(html_source, options) {
>     return style_html(html_source, options, window.js_beautify, window.css_beautify);
> };
> ```

The global is called `html_beautify`, not `style_html` (which is a function that is only used internally).

Comment: I still get the same error as before when calling that function.

Comment: @user1563232 — I don't: http://jsbin.com/fiquvu/1/edit?html,console,output